# Visual Studio Emulator for Android keyboard mapping

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

Android SDK has [a document for the mapping between Emulated Device Key and Keyboard Key](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html). That is not applicable to Visual Studio Emulator for Android.  Could anyone offer a tip on where I can find this mapping information for Visual Studio Emulator for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS Emulator for Android only maps the direct keys from Windows--the keys are the same as if the keyboard were plugged into the Android device directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elucidation, John.  Do you happen to know the PC keyboard key equivalent to the Android menu key?

Comment: I don't think there is one.